# Can I have a standalone clause in ActiveRecord?

Tags: active-record-query

I want to factor out the where clause in my two queries like this:

```
where_clause = where("(created_at >= ? and created_at < ?) or (updated_at >= ? and updated_at < ?)", range_start_date, range_end_date, range_start_date, range_end_date)
@book_instances = BookInstance.limit(pagination.items_per_page).
    offset((pagination.page - 1) * pagination.items_per_page).
    where_clause.
    order(:id)
@pagination.total_items = BookInstance.where_clause.count
```

But ActiveRecord is not happy.  I thought you could break out the query bits independently.

Comment: Could I somehow use a Model.scoped methodology (anonymous scope) here?   E.g.: http://webjazz.blogspot.com/2008/06/anonymous-scope-unknown-cousin-of-named.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, though I'm still wondering if I'm missing another nicer way:

```
book_instances_in_date_range = BookInstance.where(
    "(created_at >= ? and created_at < ?) or (updated_at >= ? and updated_at < ?)",
    range_start_date, range_end_date, range_start_date, range_end_date)

@pagination.total_items = book_instances_in_date_range.count

@book_instances = book_instances_in_date_range.limit(pagination.items_per_page).
    offset((pagination.page - 1) * pagination.items_per_page).
    order(:id)
```